# How can I fix org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException: The character '' is an invalid XML character?

Tags: java, html, xml

I using java to create HTML file from text, but I have an exception (LSException):
How can I fix "org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException: The character '' is an invalid XML character?"

**UPDATE: CODE**

`DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();` `DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");`
            `LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();`
            `LSOutput output = impl.createLSOutput();`
            `output.setEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());`
            `writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", true);`
            `output.setCharacterStream(outputStream);`
            `processDocument(doc);`
            **`writer.write(getDocument(), output);`**

Comment: Perhaps you could show your code?

Comment: share that xml line where are you getting error?

Comment: Most probably your HTML file is not a valid xhtml/xml file.

Comment: Make sure you're using ASCII quotes, not Microsoft quotes. Make sure the quotes appear where they're allowed. Agree with @MiyaG that we need to see the document you're trying to parse, or at least the part of it that's failing, to say more than that.